# Flush-left and flush-right in same toc entry with dots in-between

Tags: table-of-contents, multilingual

I have a multilingual document, which has chinese and its english translation side by side. I want to have a table of contents with section titles in both languages. Currently, an entry looks like this:

01-01: 新的一年,新的开始。 — A new year, a new beginning. . . . . . . . . . 4

and is generated by this code (only by the first line, but just to illustrate how the structure works):

```latex
\subsection[01-01: 新的一年，新的开始。 --- A new year, a new beginning.]{新的一年，新的开始。}
\subsection*{A new year, a new beginning.}
```

What I'm looking for is that the "dynamic" dots are between the languages, so that chinese is flush-left, and english is flush-right. I hope this makes it more readable, because with varying title lengths, it's a bit chaotic currently. Goal would be like this:

01-01: 新的一年,新的开始。. . . . . . . . . . A new year, a new beginning 4

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?